# ¿Cómo solucionar error ExecuteScalar: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado?

Tags: asp.net, sql

Estoy creando una clase en ASP.NET que accede a una base de datos (esta clase es un login) pero al momento de ejecutarla me muestra el siguiente error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ExecuteScalar: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado.

El código completo es el siguiente:

```
 public class UserBusinessLogic
{
    public int CheckUserLogin(ClsLogin User)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(conStr);
        SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand();
        comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter Parameters = new SqlParameter();

        Parameters = new SqlParameter();
        Parameters.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        Parameters.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        Parameters.Size = 150;
        Parameters.ParameterName = "@NombreUsuario";
        Parameters.Value = User.NombreUsuario;

        Parameters = new SqlParameter();
        Parameters.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        Parameters.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        Parameters.Size = 20;
        Parameters.ParameterName = "@Contrasena";
        Parameters.Value = User.Contrasena;

        conObj.Open();

        return Convert.ToInt32(comObj.ExecuteScalar());
        
    }
}
```

Comment: en conStr, inicializas SqlConnection y el Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás asignando la conexión `conObj` a tu objeto `SqlCommand comObj`.

Esto debería solucionarlo:

```
SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("<nombre del procedure>", conObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu valor para inicializar la conexión (`conStr`) no es correcto o esta vacío:

```
string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(conStr);
```

puede ser una razón por la que obtienes el error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: ExecuteScalar: la propiedad Connection no se
>   ha inicializado

También el otro detalle pudiera ser que no estas inicializando correctamente SqlCommand:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mi_Query, conObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta claro que no asignas en el objeto `SqlCommand`

- el nombre del stored procedure
- la instancia de `SqlConnection`

pero ademas podrias reducir mucho el código si defines mejor los parametros.

```
public class UserBusinessLogic
{
    public int CheckUserLogin(ClsLogin User)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using(SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            conObj.Open();

            SqlCommand comObj = new SqlCommand("<<nombre procedure>>", conObj);
            comObj.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            comObj.Parameters.Add("@NombreUsuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.NombreUsuario;
            comObj.Parameters.Add("@Contrasena", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = User.Contrasena;

            return Convert.ToInt32(comObj.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
}
```

Recomiendo definas el objeto de conexion dentro de un bloque `using` de esta forma el objeto se destruye de forma corecta y dejas que ado.net aplique el [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para mantener las conexiones

Comment: Una pregunta Leandro, sabes si cuando se instancia SqlConnection , ¿se puede agregar el Query y el "Connection String"?, por ejemplo SqlConnection(QueryandConnString), según recuerdo también se podía...

Comment: @Elenasys  hasta donde conozco nunca vi que el objeto de conexion recibiera una query. En el objeto SqlConnection solo se puede definir el connection string, la query se define en el SqlCommand, esto se puede ver en los constructores de la clase https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx